# Menu with ZSH (not completion)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm producing a whole lot of ZSH functions, and would like to provide an interactive menu to allow me to navigate to the various functions, gather required data and then invoke the functions.  I've written something like this to encapsulate the menu functionality:

```
get_input(){
  local result_name=$1
  for((i=2; i <= $ARGC; i++)); do
    echo ${argv[i]}
  done
  read x
  eval "${result_name}=$x"
}
```

invoking it like so:

```
test_get_option(){
  selected_option=''
  get_input selected_option 'heres the prompt' '1) opt 1' '2) opt 2'
  case $selected_option in
    1) do_option_1;;
    2) do_option_2;;
    *) echo "please choose a selection from the options above";;
  esac
}
```

which works, but it's clunky.  What I'd prefer is to be able to define some hierarchical data structure (XML or nested lists or whatever) to define the option tree and the functions to call.

Does anyone know of a system (or an oh-my-zsh plugin) like that?